# Storing BLOBS per record or one column on Android App

Tags: java, android, sqlite, blob

I'm making an app wich stores 5 different pictures of an user in a SQLite Database (storing just the filepath is not an option in this case). My question is: is it better to store a record per image having a schema like this ID, ID_USER, PHOTO_TYPE(to identify the image), BLOB (e.g. User "Juanito" will have 5 records)  or store all images in one record having a schema like ID, ID_USER, BLOB_1, BLOB_2, BLOB_3, BLOB_4, BLOB_5.

Please keep in mind that maybe the 5 pictures won't be taken at same day, so the second scheme maybe remains with empty fields.

Comment: How many users? How large are the images?

Comment: @CL. Hello, about 100 users 200kb per image. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite stores all the data in a row together, so reading a column's value implies that all previous columns are read.
Furthermore, when doing changes, the entire row is written.

This means that the database is likely to be more efficient when you do not have multiple large blobs in the same row.